# Missing shipping address and note to seller in the create payment response

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using REST API to create a payment (in sandbox environment) with payment_method="paypal". For some reason I don't get shipping address in the payer_info object in the response. I am also not sure how to obtain "notes to seller" via REST API. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Help anyone??

Comment: @user1886877 Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Not really ... I end up using Stripe instead.

Answer (score 2):

Shipping address data is not currently returned for PayPal transactions in the REST API's we offer, unless a shipping address was initially submitted along with the request.

Our new REST API's are evolving as we speak however - I'm seeing all your requests for it though, so I'm definitely passing that information on.

In the interim you could perhaps consider making another call to our classic `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` API. This would only need the Express Checkout token (EC-xxxxx), classic API username, API password and API signature and return the shipping address data (amongst other things) to you in the response ([docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up making my own shipping address form. What do you mean when you say, "unless a shipping address was initially submitted along with the request"? I tried to provide one on the payerInfo and it was invalid. Is that the correct place?

Comment: Any chance you guys (PayPal) can get the BETA API to send back the payer information shipping address, without requiring it be submitted first? Every paypal express checkout clearly shows the PayPal user's shipping address, hence the shipping info is already available at PayPal... why not simply provide it within the payer_info object? It couldn't take more than a day to implement/test/release, right? It's one of those things that seems it would make or break adoption of the new REST API. Just my two cents, my respect to the peeps working on it. :-)

Comment: @PayPal_Robert Will you at LEAST update the docs with a note? I wasted an entire week on the company's dime before you replied to an email. Also...You told me this was a bug. I've since been informed it may take over a year to "fix" as it has not yet been implemented. What's the real story?

Answer (score 0):

Shipping address is now supported to the Paypal REST Api.  Set the ShippingAddress object and then add it to the ItemList object

```
 $shippingAddress = new ShippingAddress();
 $shippingAddress->setLine1($_POST['shipstreet'])
->setCity($_POST['shipcity'])
->setState($_POST['shipstate'])
->setPostalCode($_POST['shipzip'])
->setCountryCode($_POST['shipcountry'])
->setRecipientName($_POST['shipname']);

 $itemList = new ItemList();
 $itemList->setItems($itemsarr); //my array of items
 $itemList->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);
```

You might want to sanitize your POST vars before you send them.  Some other interesting notes, you can set the payer_info first name and last name as well as the email address.

```
 $payerinfo = new PayerInfo();
 $payerinfo->setEmail($_POST['email'])
->setFirstName($_POST['firstName'])
->setLastName($_POST['lastName']);

 $payer = new Payer();
 $payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
->setPayerInfo($payerinfo)
->setFundingInstruments(array($fi));
```